# Creating Buttons in JFrame

Tags: java, button, random, jframe

I'm trying to write a code that adds a student and will display all their information. Also I want it to display 10 times what the student is up to using the method whatIsUp().  I am not sure how to get my array onto the button.

app.java

```
public class  app
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    myJFrame mjf = new myJFrame();
    student student1 = new student ("John", "Smith");

  }
}
```

myJFrame.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class myJFrame extends JFrame
{
    public myJFrame ()
    {
        super ("My Frame");
//------------------------------------------------------
// Create components: Jpanel
        myPanel mjp = new myPanel();
        getContentPane().add(mjp,"Center");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize (700, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

myPanel.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.UIManager.get;

public class myPanel extends JPanel {
    public myPanel ()
    {
       setBackground(new Color(200, 190, 255));
       JButton b1 = new JButton(get.whatsUp1());
       b1.setBackground(Color.green);
       add(b1);
       JButton b2 = new JButton(get.whatsUp1());
       b2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
       add(b2);
       JButton b3 = new JButton(get.whatsUp1());
       b3.setBackground(Color.magenta);
       add(b3);
       JButton b4 = new JButton(get.whatsUp1());
       b4.setBackground(Color.magenta);
       add(b4);
       JButton b5 = new JButton(get.whatsUp1());
       b5.setBackground(Color.magenta);
       add(b5);
       JButton b6 = new JButton(get.whatsUp1());
       b6.setBackground(Color.magenta);
       add(b6);
       JButton b7 = new JButton(get.whatsUp1());
       b7.setBackground(Color.magenta);
       add(b7);
       JButton b8 = new JButton(get.whatsUp1());
       b8.setBackground(Color.magenta);
       add(b8);
       JButton b9 = new JButton(get.whatsUp1());
       b9.setBackground(Color.magenta);
       add(b9);
       JButton b10 = new JButton(get.whatsUp1());
       b10.setBackground(Color.magenta);
       add(b10);

}
}
```

And my student.java

```
public class student {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String[] whatsUp = {"walking","sleeping","in class","studying"};


    student(String myFirstName, String myLastName)
    {
    firstName = myFirstName;
    lastName= myLastName;
    }

    String getName()
    {
    return firstName + " " +lastName;
    }



    //--------METHODS---------
        String getInfo()
        {
        return "Name = " + firstName + " " + lastName;

        }

        String whatsUp1()
        {
        double rn = Math.random();
        double rn_max5 = rn * 4;
        int ri_max5 = (int) rn_max5;
        return whatsUp[ri_max5];




}
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? If you want to dynamically trigger actions when clicking on a button, you'll have to use ActionListeners

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass a reference to the student created in the main(). this student will be passed to the JFrame and then to the JPanel. so i change the constructors to take a student as an argument. Another advice - please keep the naming convention so classes will start with capital letter (i didnt change to keep your code) :

```
public class  app
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    student student1 = new student ("John", "Smith");
    myJFrame mjf = new myJFrame(student1);


  }
}
```

-

```
public class myJFrame extends JFrame {
    public myJFrame(student s) {
        super("My Frame");
        // ------------------------------------------------------
        // Create components: Jpanel
        myPanel mjp = new myPanel(s);
        getContentPane().add(mjp, "Center");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(700, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

-

```
public class myPanel extends JPanel {
    public myPanel(student s) {
        setBackground(new Color(200, 190, 255));
        JButton b1 = new JButton(s.whatsUp1());
        b1.setBackground(Color.green);
        add(b1);
        JButton b2 = new JButton(s.whatsUp1());
        b2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        add(b2);
        JButton b3 = new JButton(s.whatsUp1());
        b3.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        add(b3);
        JButton b4 = new JButton(s.whatsUp1());
        b4.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        add(b4);
        JButton b5 = new JButton(s.whatsUp1());
        b5.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        add(b5);
        JButton b6 = new JButton(s.whatsUp1());
        b6.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        add(b6);
        JButton b7 = new JButton(s.whatsUp1());
        b7.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        add(b7);
        JButton b8 = new JButton(s.whatsUp1());
        b8.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        add(b8);
        JButton b9 = new JButton(s.whatsUp1());
        b9.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        add(b9);
        JButton b10 = new JButton(s.whatsUp1());
        b10.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        add(b10);

    }
}
```